# Erro em JSON. O meu código não consegue ler o JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Eu devo criar uma pagina que mostre um catálogo de álbuns fornecidos em xml. Daí tenho que transformar o catálogo.xml em JSON e mostrar ele em uma tabela com artista e com Título. O problema é que meu código não lê o documento pois fala que há tags inválidas.

Erro fornecido no Google Chrome: VM40:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
     at JSON.parse ()
     at myFunction (Teste.html:29)
     at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (Teste.html:15)
myFunction @ Teste.html:29
xhttp.onreadystatechange @ Teste.html:15
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
loadDoc @ Teste.html:19
onclick @ Teste.html:5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>XMLHttpRequest</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Catálogo</button>
<br><br>
<p id="tabelaId"></p>

</body>
<script>
function loadDoc(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  myFunction(this);
  }
 };
xhttp.open("GET", 
"http://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/fundamentosWeb/paginaCatalogo.php", 
 true);
 xhttp.send();
 }
 function myFunction(response) {
 var i;
 console.log (response.responseText);

 var xmlDoc = response.responseText;  

 var table="<table border=1  style=border-collapse:'collapse'; ><tr> 
 <th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";

 var x = JSON.parse(xmlDoc); 
   for (i = 0; i <x.length;i++) { 
     table += "<tr><td>" +
     xmlDoc+"</td></tr>";
   }

 document.getElementById("tabelaId").innerHTML = table;
 }
 </script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como usar `JSON.parse` para converter uma string XML em JSON.

Como você está recebendo um XML como resposta, troque o `responseText` por `responseXML` para que o retorno já venha parseado em formato XML, caso contrário virá como string.

Depois basta percorrer todas as tags `ALBUM` e pegar o texto da tag que você deseja e ir concatenando na variável `table`. Quando for fazer o `innerHTML` tem que fechar a tabela com `</table>`:

```
function loadDoc(){
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         myFunction(this);
      }
   };

   xhttp.open("GET", 
   "http://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/fundamentosWeb/paginaCatalogo.php", 
   true);
   xhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(response) {
   var xmlDoc = response.responseXML;
   var table="<table border=1  style=border-collapse:'collapse'; ><tr> <th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";

   var albuns = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ALBUM");

   for (var i = 0; i <albuns.length;i++) { 
      var art = albuns[i].querySelector("ARTIST").textContent;
      var tit = albuns[i].querySelector("TITLE").textContent;
      table += "<tr><td>"+art+"</td>"
      +"<td>"+tit+"</td></tr>";
   }

   document.getElementById("tabelaId").innerHTML = table+"</table>";
}
```

O resultado final será algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Orbigado pela resposta. Fiquei com uma dúvida quanto a um trecho do código. Gostaria de saber o que exatamente esse query selector faz. Ele interpreta as tags<> ? Por exemplo: <catalogo><album><artist> Bob<artist><album><catalogo>   Aí ele vai exatamente no texto da tag que eu escolho  ou isso é por causa do text content ?

Comment: Opa! É apenas um seletor. Vc pode selecionar a tag que quiser.